# align - rotate scale transform two images opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

I have master/golden picture that I want to align another picture that capture to it.
the diff can be in the angle(not that much) and in the scale.
of course also in the brightness and point of view of the camera(again not that much).
when I take the master/golden picture I set known position for the object that interest me, in this case it led. **I must do it becuase if one led not turn off I need to know reporting which one is missing, so the known position is mainly for knowing which led are missing.** so I do the alignment to search in the known position the led I want to analyze.
for example, this is the master/golden picture,
be noted that the black rectangle is to demonstrate what I am searching for, its not blended on the picture.(only the rectangle around the led).
[image: golden picture]

image I capture to align:
[image: image to align]

what have I try:

1. perspective transform using 2/4 anchor from the golden picture.
2. using algoritem like surf/sift.

surf/sift gave me better result then the first option, but still I have some issues(the led get out of the rectangle).
see below after the alignment, the led are out of the rectangle(no all of them)
[image: failed picture]

increase the rectangle size its not an option because the led are too close to each other.
I think the issue with the sift it that it take wrong matches. I try to avoid them without success.
How I try to avoid wrong matches:

1. I know for a fact that the angle won't change significantly, so I tried to ignore twin points that have a large slope between them Using this code: `good = [m for m in good if abs((kpts1[m.queryIdx].pt[1] - kpts2[m.trainIdx].pt[1])/(kpts1[m.queryIdx].pt[0] - kpts2[m.trainIdx].pt[0] ))<0.5]`  but it didn't worked as I can still saw matches with big slope.

I think maybe the solution for me is to eliminate matches with slope or matches that are not in the same are by giving threshold to the match point, but I am not sure how to do it.

anyone have a solution for me? maybe try something diff then sift/perspective transform?

all the code I am using:

```
imgname1 = options.source_path
imgname2 = options.output_path

img1 = cv2.imread(imgname1)
img2 = cv2.imread(imgname2)
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
# orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=1500)

matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(dict(algorithm = 1, trees = 5), {})
# bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING,crossCheck=True)

kpts1, descs1 = surf.detectAndCompute(gray1,None)
kpts2, descs2 = surf.detectAndCompute(gray2,None)
# kpts1, descs1 = orb.detectAndCompute(gray1,None)
# kpts2, descs2 = orb.detectAndCompute(gray2,None)

matches = matcher.knnMatch(descs1, descs2,2)
# matches = bf.match(descs1,descs2)
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x[0].distance)

good = [m1 for (m1, m2) in matches if m1.distance < 0.7 * m2.distance]
    
# good = matches[:50]
good = [m for m in good if abs((kpts1[m.queryIdx].pt[1] - kpts2[m.trainIdx].pt[1])/(kpts1[m.queryIdx].pt[0] - kpts2[m.trainIdx].pt[0] ))>1]

canvas = img2.copy()

if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kpts1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kpts2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    # for pt_src in src_pts:
    #     print(pt_src[0][0])
    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RHO ,5.0) #try to use RANCA, but RHO gave me the best results.
    h,w = img1.shape[:2]
    pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)
    cv2.polylines(canvas,[np.int32(dst)],True,(0,255,0),3, cv2.LINE_AA)
else:
    print( "Not enough matches are found - {}/{}".format(len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT))


matched = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kpts1,canvas,kpts2,good,None,flags=2)

h,w = img1.shape[:2]
pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)
perspectiveM = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(np.float32(dst),pts)
found = cv2.warpPerspective(img2,perspectiveM,(w,h))
orig_path = options.output_path
path = re.split("/",orig_path)
orig_path = orig_path.replace(path[-1],"")
with open(orig_path + '/matrix_transform.pkl', 'wb') as outp:
    pickle.dump(perspectiveM, outp, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    pickle.dump(w, outp, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    pickle.dump(h, outp, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

cv2.imwrite(orig_path + "/matched.jpg", matched)
my_str = imgname2
substr = ".jpg"
inserttxt = "_transform"
idx = my_str.index(substr)
my_str = my_str[:idx] + inserttxt + my_str[idx:]
print(my_str)
cv2.imwrite(my_str, found)
```

Comment: are you able to detect the LED center points? If yes, you might want to try cv::minAreaRect around them and just match/align the two rotated rectangles.

Comment: Hi @Micka, i am not sure how it going to help, maybe i didnt understand you, you say to search all the led in the image i want to align, and then match the two picture using the led position? can you elaborate when you talking on the golden picture and when on the image i want to align? thank you!

Comment: as you say it correctly, there are multuple steps. 1. search/know all led positions in the golden image, 2, search all leds in the query image, 3. match them. Did you already solve points 1 and 2? Then step 3 might be solvable with my suggestion.

Comment: findHomography uses more degrees of freedom than you need here. use one of the other APIs that finds some affine or rigid or more constrained transform

Comment: Get the contours of the two boxes. Then get the rotated bounding boxes of each using minAreaRect.  That will tell your the angles of rotation of each. Now rotate one to the other angle by rotating by the difference in angles.

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz, can you reference or advise on specific API that I should try?

Comment: browse calib3d module docs, find estimateAffinePartial2D, estimateAffine2D. that will at least fix the unstable solutions that introduce perspective transformation where none should happen (that one pic where you circled a dot not hitting the center of a square). -- in general, I'd recommend presenting a [mre], i.e. required source *data*, without any illustrative scribbles on it